# Links to comments oneboxed in chat don't render relative links correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat, onebox

If you one-box a comment in chat like [this one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27373775#27373775) which contains a "From Review" link, clicking on it in chat results in a Page Not Found. Further inspection of the link shows that a relative path is being used:

```
 <a href="/review/low-quality-posts/10474622">From Review </a>
```

So it tries to go to

```
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10474622
```

Instead of:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10474622
```

Comment: Test comment [relative link](/q/311901).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed now and relative links in comments should one-box correctly in general.

Unfortunately, this change isn't retroactive, so all existing one-boxes will still be busted up.

Holler at me if you see any weird comment one-box behavior as a result, since, as we all know...

> [image]

Comment: Tested and works: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27811900#27811900

Answer (score 10):

Actually, *any* relative link in a one-boxed comment does not work. See https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27378404#27378404 for the place where I one-boxed my comment on the question (which contains one).

The coments source is:

```
Test comment [relative link](/q/311901).
```

Comment: So... maybe the change needs to be made in the one-boxing process to convert relative paths to absolute paths. Changing it in one place will fix a symptom, but not the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's it.